# Unexpected reserved word 'yield' in redux saga reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I started with reactredux saga and this is my code for currentUserSaga.js.
***currentUserSaga.js***

```
import {delay} from 'redux-saga'
export function* currentUserSaga () {
    while(true){
        yield delay(1000);
        console.info("User Saga loop");
    }
}
```

While compiling I am getting following error.

> SyntaxError: /home/Sakthy/Desktop/React
> Saga/redux-saga-cart/src/sagas/currentUserSaga.js: Unexpected reserved
> word 'yield' (4:8)  2 | export function currentUserSaga () {  3 |
> while(true){> 4 |         yield delay(1000);    |         ^  5 |
> console.info("User Saga loop");  6 |     }  7 | }

Please guide me I am following a tutorial but I think it's due to wrong use case of yield keyword.

Comment: try importing delay from `redux-saga/effects`

Comment: I should warn you that `yield` is not a best practice for your solution at all. The best way to prevent this error is to try to find another way of solving the problem you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

we expect generating functions to generate a value, and remember that the yield must return a value at each iterate, not a function that does not return anything.